# Solr can get result like mysql DATE function with solr TZ date format

Tags: date, solr

For solr 5.2 is there any way to get result by specifying only given date `YYYY-MM-DD` like MySQL `DATE()` function ?

**Example.**

In MySQL Query: NOTE: Date fields type - datetime

```
SELECT group_field, COUNT(id) AS TOT FROM TABLE WHERE
DATE(date_modify) = "YYYY-MM-DD" AND
DATE(date_create) != DATE(date_modify)
GROUP BY group_field, DATE(date_modify)
```

How this apply in Solr ?

In Solr date field like : `date_create_dt`, `date_modify_dt` with `TZ` format `YYYY-MM-DDTH:i:SZ`

Answer (score 0):

as per your requirement you can use this way

`2015-06-25T` same as `[2015-06-25T00:00:00Z TO 2015-06-25T23:59:59Z]`

this is just a day...

you can use it in solr query as

```
&fq=created_date:[2015-06-01T00:00:00Z TO NOW]
```

or

```
&fq=published_date:[2015-06-25T00:00:00Z TO 2015-06-25T23:59:59Z]
```

if you want know more option on the same please refer the link which tell you how date format works in solr [solr date formats](https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/lweug/Solr+Date+Format)

Comment: In that we got just result, but can't compare two date.
Like  DATE(date_create) != DATE(date_modify)

Comment: check if function could sole your issue...https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#ms

Comment: That not help.
As solr doc contain date and time while need to group by only yyyy-mm-dd,
Also compare only yyyy-mm-dd